# How to concatenate URL with input text in Vue

Tags: vue.js, url, return, concatenation, vuejs3

I need a little help with concatenation in Vue. I have an input field where I enter some username and I want to concatenate it with the URL in my data. Here is my code

```
<input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Username" id='username' v-model="usersrc">
<div v-for="item in storedData" :key="item.id">
                <a :href="item.link" target="_blank">
                    <p>{{item.name}}</p>
                    <p  :id="item.id + 'availability'"></p>
                </a>
            </div>

export default {
components: {
    AppLayout,
 },  
     data() {
    return {
        usersrc: this.usersrc,
        items: [
            {id:1, name: "Facebook" ,link:"https://facebook.com/${{usersrc}}"}, and so on
```

My purpose is to get the whole URL with the username in the  tag in div element. When I click on it, for example if I enter test, to get the https://facebook.com/test URL.
Also I have tried like this

```
link:"https://facebook.com/+'usersrc'"
link:"https://facebook.com/{{usersrc}}"
```

But nothing works. I am new in Vue, so I would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly achieve this in the template by using [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

In addition, I just added a check that if there is no value in input box then links should not be shown. You can remove this check based on your requirement.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    usersrc: null,
    items: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Facebook', link: 'https://facebook.com/' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Instagram', link: 'https://instagram.com/' }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Username" id='username' v-model="usersrc">
  <div v-if="usersrc">
    <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
      <a :href="`${item.link}${usersrc}`" target="_blank">
        <p>{{item.name}}</p>
        <p :id="item.id + 'availability'"></p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, but what if there is for example facebook.com./${usersrc}?lang=en or some other additions to the link after the username? @rohìt-jíndal

Comment: @Lindsay from where we will get this addition parameters `?lang=en`  ? If these are hardcoded we can achieve that like `:href="`${item.link}${usersrc}?lang=en`"` or if these are dynamic then we can do like this : `:href="`${item.link}${usersrc}?lang=${lang}`"`

Comment: Yes, they will be dynamic so thanks for the solution again @Rohìt Jíndal

Comment: the thing is that I also need to check the availability of the username, so that is why I need it to concatenate it in data. The problem with the <a> tag is solved, but how can I do it in the data to make sure that the username is checked? @rohìt-jíndal

Comment: @Lindsay Those are third party social media app urls. How will you check the availability ? You don't have control on their data. May be you have to use their API's to check that entered username is available in `facebook` and `instagram` or not.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
link:"'https://facebook.com/'+usersrc"
```

or better with alt+96

```
link:"`https://facebook.com/`+usersrc"
```

Comment: I tried thanks, but still it does not work @Joe

Answer (score 0):

data() function execute only once when component render. so we need to update that data manually when something is change. and also use single curly braces in backtick.

```
watch:{
 usersrc(newVal){
   this.items =  this.items.map(item=> {
        return {...item,link:`https://facebook.com/${usersrc}`})
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: where should I call usersrc if I write it this way? @meet-vaghsiya

Comment: @Lindsay why you want to call usersrc ? and what is it mean ? 
it is not function , so you can not call this ?

and if you worry about updated value of usersrc, than this watchers will automatically called when userstc will changed.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, maybe the problem is elsewhere ? I juste noticed that you wrote in data :

```
usersrc: this.usersrc
```

I would suggest using a default value like an empty array, because what you have in data can be accessible via 'this' in the script, so this would be redundant.

Does it work if you replace this line by
`usersrc: ''` ?

Comment: No, it did not work, but thanks for the suggestion :) @gvaillant